# How to end FTP session in Chrome, to log in with different credentials?

Tags: google-chrome, ftp, login, session

I've just opened an FTP site through Chrome which requires authentication, and I've logged in with some credentials.

Now I need to re-log in on that FTP with some different credentials. How can I make Chrome forget about the previous session and ask me for credentials again?

Comment: What happens if you enter those different credentials right with the URL? Chrome can handle this like any other browser. `ftp://username:password@ftpserver/folder`

Comment: Nothing. They just become removed from the URL (as usual), and the page is loaded using the old session. In fact, this should be considered a Chrome bug.

Comment: Hm, does this happen with different browsers too? Second try: What happens if you clear all password data and history (CTRL+SHIFT+DEL?)

Comment: Firefox successfully clears current session if you enter new credentials via URL, even if they are wrong (first notifies the 503 code, then when you reload poage it asks for new credentials).

Comment: If you take a look at the checkboxes available in the clear user data, it's obvious that none will clear an FTP session. And as expected, I checked all, and the session was not cleared.

Comment: I'm firmly in the "never use a browser for ftp" camp.  *CoreFtp* for example is much easier to use, allows storage of multiple access names, etc etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there's absolutely no way to do that - **exactly logging off the FTP server** - at least with versions between 2013 Q4 and 2018 Q1. There are some good workarounds anyhow listed in the answers below.

Comment: ... actually above.

Answer (score 6):

Opening a new incognito window worked for me.

Comment: This doesn't wipe the chrome ftp session, but it's a cool workaround!

Answer (score 4):

The healthiest and the easiest way to end FTP session in Google Chrome might be only using Chrome Incognito mode for FTP processes, then closing it when finished those FTP processes.

> You can launch incognito by pressing Ctrl + Shift + N, (or) Settings -> New incognito Window, (or) right mouse-click on a link from a regular Chrome session, and select “open link in incognito window”.

Technically ending a FTP session in Google Chrome is complicated or maybe impossible. It only lets you keep connected to FTP server during a single browser session. In most of other browsers this situation is controllable. For example; You can resume to download a file from a FTP server even you have rebooted the system in Firefox FTP session.

Waiting a while to end the FTP session is not also a solution, because cache files are not deleted when Chrome returns ERR_TIMED_OUT. Refreshing page brings credentials of the FTP session back.

Unfortunatelly, there is no suitable solution yet for Google Chrome that I know.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and Just closed the chrome and re-open it.

Comment: The OP has already stated  that this does not work for them.

Comment: This could work or none depending on the session handling of the FTP server

Answer (score -1):

It's better to use an *Incognito Window* (Ctrl+Shift+N), but if you forget, you can clear your credentials like this:

1) Clear all history and data (Ctrl+Shift+Del), e.g. from the last 24 hours

2) Restart Chrome

However, it's best to download a dedicated application for this, like FileZilla or WinSCP, because Chrome doesn't end FTP sessions.

Comment: As stated in comment above, that doesn't end FTP sessions

Comment: @ÁxelCostasPena Yes, it doesn't end FTP sessions, buy you can log in with different credentials as you ask. I apologize for my incomplete answer, now it should be better.

Comment: Nover mind, it's just for being precise on getting an answer to the exact question title.